# SaaS with Desktop Client. Security and Peformance

Tags: performance, wcf, security, certificate, saas

I have multiple question about SaaS.

Can we have SaaS with desktop client or SaaS should have web client?

We have a system which clients connect to services over internet, for security reason we use certificate(I mean, we use WCF with message security and certificate for clientCredentialType):

```
<security mode="Message">
      <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
</security>
```

The problem is **long delay** and **low performance** of the service. It take long time to service response. what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

SaaS is a licensing and delivery model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service), it does not limit your client technologies. It's just natural for a SaaS to use the web.

The problem with long delay and low performance is not related to SaaS. It could be related to a bad internet connection, bad programming or bad configuration of the web server.